# teraterm script constructing a string that is the same name as a constant

Tags: ttl, teraterm

I have defined the constant registers with the following addresses:
MDIO3_CTL       = '0x08c0f034'
MDIO4_CTL       = '0x08c13034'
... etc.

Based on the MDIO number (ex: 3 or 4), I want to do a memory display (md) of that register.

```
macnum ='3'
mac = 'MDIO'
strconcat mac macnum
strconcat mac '_CTL'
sendln  'md ' mac ' 1 '
wait Uboot
```

When I do the sendln, I see 'md MDIO3_CTL 1' instead of 'md 0x08c0f034 1'. Can someone help me?